# JDeveloer running too slow, CPU load

Tags: load, cpu, jdeveloper

My JDeveloper is running too slow when I open any application. When I choose to open a file or to move the cursor to write something I have to wait a long time before the application turns back to normal work. I have noticed that it is continuous action and it is very uncomfortable. Moreover, when I open the task manger window I see 30% CPU load (My CPU is 3.5GHZ). I have read some articles in the web and tried some actions but there is no result.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What JDev version and what have tried specifically ?

Comment: The version is Studio Edition Version 12.1.3.0. I tried to change the memory settings in "ide\bin\ide.conf"  file but there was no effect.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the CPU loading by JDev, but I do now how to repair it or to find why it is caused. Is it possible to be something with the memory?